# Onomatopoeia for stomach growling?

Tags: word-choice, onomatopoeia, sounds

I've been thinking.

How do I put the sound of growling stomach into words?

I'm also curious about the Onomatopoeia for chewing food and swallowing water.

Comment: Isn't _growl_ already onomatopoeic ? _Munch_ and _Gulp_ as @CJDennis has said for the other two.

Comment: @Frank You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @user867 I think CJDennis should take the credit; 2/3rds of my comment is his answer and _growl_ was in the question already.

Comment: @Frank: You are right but there are more mimetic versions of onomatopoeic words also. Like baa, brr, grr. It is almost like the onomatopoeia of an onomatopoeic word but linguistically less structured.  Baa is a special case because it is the mimetic version of bleat and bleat lost its onomatopoeic connotations in time.

Comment: @ermanen I know we're not here for discussion but I don't think _bleat_ has lost it's onomatopoeia, has it?. _bleat_ for a lamb or a goat and _baa_ for a sheep seems to be the right sound; lambs and  goats definitely don't _baa_, they _bleeeaaaat_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Stomach: grr
- Swallowing: gulp
- Chewing: chew or munch

Comment: "chomp chomp" for chewing also.

Answer (score 2):

**Gurgle** could fit.

> 'Gurgle, gurgle' went my stomach, as I waited for the bus. I was hungry.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the word 'borborygmus' (plural: borborygmi)

Comment: That's a very interesting word and although it may have had an onomatopoetically derived origin it is not an onomatopoeia in English. I would never say "My stomach went borborygmus"!

Comment: This is the medical term for stomach rumbling.

Comment: This has nothing to do with onomatopoeia.

Comment: +1 In my view this medical term is almost perfectly onomatopoeic (except for the final s).

Answer (score 1):

rumble, gurgle, grumble, growl, rumble. And maybe just a simple *Grrrr*